# WordPress - Fatal error: Call to a member function when calling class

Tags: php, wordpress, class

I have created a php class in my theme function.php

```
class myWidgetSetting {

    function get_title(){
     //some blah blah code
    }

}

$setting = new myWidgetSetting();
```

but when I call this class `$setting->get_title()` inside:

```
class myWidget extends WP_Widget { 
    function renderLayout(){
    global $setting;
            $setting->get_title();
    }
}
```

Then I get this error:

**Fatal error: Call to a member function get_title() on a non-object in D:\wamp\www\wp-content\themes\twentyten\widgets\myWidget.php on line 3**

Do i need to register class to wordpress ??

Comment: class myWidget extends WP_Widget should be class myWidget extends myWidgetSetting

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert on PHP but to use `$setting` variable as global you need to declare it as such.

Like this:

```
global $setting;
$setting = new myWidgetSetting();
```